# Node.js http.ClientRequest: get raw headers

Tags: cookies, node.js

I am using Node.js 0.2.3 and response.headers['set-cookie'] seems to be truncated after the first cookie. Is there any way I can just read the raw headers?

BTW, the set-cookie header should contain:

```
id1=sw34rwdsfsd;secure;
id2=wer235sd2354;secure;
id3=df435df4543;secure
```

My guess would be it is not parsing the boolean attributes right and stops after the first one. Anyone know if this is fixed in later versions of Node.js (even though I can't upgrade just yet)?

Comment: I really recommend going to a newer version of node anyway. The team has said that the 0.4 api will be pretty stable, and a lot has changed since 0.2. The longer you wait the harder it will be to migrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

    function getHeader(url, callback){
      var client = spawn('curl', ['-I', url]);
      client.stdout.setEncoding('***');
      client.stdout.on('data', function(data){
        callback(data);
      });
    }
```

The -I flag asks curl for just the header. Pass whatever encoding to setEncoding - I think it defaults to the raw that you're looking for.