# http.clientResponse - Way to get 'reasonPhrase'?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using node.js now for almost 2 years for different things. But today was the first time, I wanted to get the 'reasonPhrase' or 'statusMessage' from a clientResponse created using http.request().

There isn't a property I could access. At least there isn't one defined in the docs.
Is there a way to get it?

Thanks very much!

Comment: a workaround http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453322/node-js-http-clientrequest-get-raw-headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this information is not available thorugh the http-parser that node.js uses.

I've now started a feature request on both node.js and http-parser to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

The following works in node v0.8.x (but not v0.10.x)

```
var http = require('http');

var clientRequest = http.get("http://www.stackoverflow.com", function(res) {
    console.log("statusCode=" + res.statusCode);
});

clientRequest.on('socket', function(socket) {
    socket.once('data', function(buffer) {
        console.log("reasonPhrase=" + buffer.toString().
                    match(/^HTTP.+ \d+ (.*)(\n|\r).*/)[1]);
    });
});
```